# Why the bottom of the page is not cropping my absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I have two `<div>` with the `position: absolute`. One is at the top and the other is at the bottom the page. The one at the bottom of the page goes lower than the last element (footer). My problem is that even if my `<div>` is in `position: absolute` and should be removed from the flow, my page extends to fit the `<div>` that is "overflowing". How can I make the page crop everything that exceeds my footer?

Here's what I'm talking about:

```css
body{
  position: relative;
}

p{
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}

footer{
  margin-top: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.bg_gradient.first{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  
  transform: translate(-400px, -400px);
  
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(254,73,70,1) 0%, rgba(254,73,70,0) 70%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.bg_gradient.last{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  
  transform: translate(-400px, 400px);
  
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(254,73,70,1) 0%, rgba(254,73,70,0) 70%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum voluptas incidunt nulla necessitatibus rerum illum provident ea earum neque officia nam deserunt animi nostrum iusto velit distinctio, dolor eveniet voluptates.</p>
  
  <div class="bg_gradient first"></div>
  
  <div class="bg_gradient last"></div>
  
  <footer>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere eligendi maiores dolore mollitia animi a fugit saepe perferendis unde, sequi debitis sint ratione, recusandae tempora quis culpa vitae sed assumenda!</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Well that is how absolute works so it is working as expected. Maybe you need to hide it if the page is not long enough with JavaScript? I assume you do not want to disable scrolling.

Comment: Yes, your css is working as intended - .bg_gradient.last is 1000x1000px, and it's shifted for 400px. Just because it's positioned absolutely does not mean it won't cause an overflow.

Comment: If you want the page not to show the second element, set max-width to the body and set overflow: hidden? But that's a strange way of doing it. The answer to your question is still: because it's not supposed to 'crop it'.

Comment: Ohhhh... I didn't know that @Mahatmasamatman I thought that if it's positioned absolutely it won't cause an overflow. I found a work around :)

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Mahatmasamatman, the things is this is the normal behavior.

> Just because an element is absolutely positioned, does not mean the parent container won't stretch to accommodate it.
>   - @Mahatmasamatman

My solution is to create a div that make the same width and height than my body with `position: absolute` and set `overflow: hidden` so I would get the behavior I wanted.
Here's a [jsfiddle with the solution](https://jsfiddle.net/xskvqm4d/)

Answer (score 5):

*Why the bottom of the page is not cropping my absolute positioned element*

It's not supposed to be cropping it. That's how it is supposed to work. Just because an element is absolutely positioned, does not mean the parent container won't stretch to accommodate it.